# How to perform order by on column by splitting the column String?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am using MySql and I have a table with the column in the form of

> first/first1/first2/first3

and

> second/second1/second2/second3

I want to perform ordering on the column ignoring the first value of every column before '/'.
i.e. perform ordering on

> first1/first2/first3

and

> second1/second2/second3

In simple words, I want to perform orderby from first value after '/'.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add same data and expected output. Try to create a fiddle at sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as a sorting criterion:

```
order by substr(col, instr(col, '/') + 1)
```

Explanation: The expression extracts the potion after the first occurrence of `/`. A refined version would cater for values without the separator char, eg.:

```
order by substr(col, coalesce(instr(col, '/'), 0) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ..... 
FROM ....
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(column FROM INSTR(column, '/') + 1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!